# Export data from dataset to excel

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel

I am trying to export data from dataset to excel and save it directly to a given path without giving me the option to open,save or cancel.

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/coolcode2_aspx.aspx

Comment: Even if u tried in Google you get a lot on this

Comment: guys i should not get the option to save the excel but it should get saved automatically at a location specified by me.

Comment: I've merged your unregistered accounts. You can now leave comments under answers, edit your question and accept an answer when the time comes to do that.

Comment: Then Simply do not flush the data out

Comment: I think it is not good to save the file in the path u specified what if the user does not have certain drive that you are saving in

Answer (score 1):

Check this  [DataSetToExcel](https://web.archive.org/web/20071211120622/http://tim.mackey.ie/HowtoExportADatasetToExcelCAspnet.aspx)

and [c# (WinForms-App) export DataSet to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373925/c-winforms-app-export-dataset-to-excel)

In the first link change the code as follows:

Remove the all code that initially starts and try the following

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter("Your Path to save"))
{
  using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
  {
    // instantiate a datagrid
    DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
    dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    dg.DataBind();
    dg.RenderControl(htw);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [ExcelLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) this is a one liner ...

```
DataSet myDataSet;
... populate data set ...
ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook("MyExcelFile.xls", myDataSet);
```

See also [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c)

Comment: I tried this.it was giving 'invalid cell value' exception.I do not see any active development on this

Comment: @shreesha I wonder if you have an error in one or more of your cell formulas?

Comment: yes @tony probably.Otherwise your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

This [C# Excel library](http://www.easyxls.com/net-excel-library) can also be used to export the dataset. More details about how to export can be found [here](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/export-dataset-to-excel.html).

```
ExcelDocument xls = new ExcelDocument();
xls.easy_WriteXLSFile_FromDataSet("ExcelFile.xls", dataset, 
                 new ExcelAutoFormat(Styles.AUTOFORMAT_EASYXLS1), "Sheet Name");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the greatest solution but here is what I did, it opens a new excel document then copies what is in the dataset, all you need to do is sort out the columns and save it.

Btw totes my first post to answer a question, hope it helps

```
        private void cmdExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("excel.exe");
            try
            {
                copyAlltoClipboard();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
                object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
                xlexcel.Visible = true;
                xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
                xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
                CR.Select();
                xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error :" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        private void copyAlltoClipboard()
        {
            dataGridViewItems.SelectAll();
            DataObject dataObj = dataGridViewItems.GetClipboardContent();
            if (dataObj != null)
                Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
        }
```

Comment: Where is the path that the OP wishes to save to ? Perhaps ask him for clarification on how he plans to specify this path and then expand on that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another C# library, which lets you export from a DataSet to an Excel 2007 .xlsx file, using the OpenXML libraries.

http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm

All of the source code is provided, free of charge, along with a demo application, and you can use this in your ASP.Net, WPF and WinForms applications.

Once you've added the class to your application, it just takes one function call to export your data into an Excel file.

```
CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(myDataSet, "C:\\Sample.xlsx");
```

It doesn't get much easier than that.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Hi i found a perfect solution [Here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/07/23/writing-data-from-a-datatable-to-excel.aspx)

Just replace 'missing.value' with System.Type.Missing in the code. Also remove

oWB.Close(System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing);
and

oXL.Quit();
from the code. Otherwise your excel will get closed automatically as soon as it open.