# store excel in specified location

Tags: c#

I want to populate the data from DataSet to Excel file and then the Excel file should be directly stored to a particular path like `C:\` and the save pop up message should not appear. Please give me specific reply on how to store it on specified location as I am able to populate the Excel and to store I am getting the pop up message window which I don't want.

Comment: Care to post some code with how you're doing it right now?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790431/export-data-from-dataset-to-excel/5790511#5790511

Answer (score 1):

Have you consider, implementing **[this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/ExcelDataTable.aspx)**?

It's pretty straight forward if read.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the solution that you are looking for](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ExportClassLibrary.aspx)