# Export dataset to Excel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, dataset, export

I want to export dataset to excel(.xls) file without any warning messages. I tried one approch which will write to excel using response.write. but its not in correct format. when i open excel i get some warning message which i should not get because i need to upload same excel to sql server after some modifications.

Please note i cant install Office on the server and i have 4 datatables in the dataset which should be exported in seperate sheets in the same excel file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export data from dataset to excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790431/export-data-from-dataset-to-excel)

Comment: Have you looked into EPPlus (http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Yeap I am using EPPlus. It does the trick. Excellent dll to quickly export data to the excel in xls or xlsx formats.