# Exporting Recordset to Excel

Tags: excel, ssis, ssis-2012, recordset

I have created an SSIS package that takes a pivot view (so the fields are dynamic) and exports it into a recordset. I was able to export the recordset to an Excel file using ActiveX, but when deployed on the server, it does not allow ActiveX. Is there an easy way to export a recordset to an Excel file otherwise? I can't use the Excel destination in SSIS because the field names are dynamic and can change.

Answer (score 0):

**You can export recordset to excel file using a Script Task (C# or VB.NET).**

You must select the recordset variable as ReadOnly Variable within the Script and implement your own logic. In order to do that, there are many examples posted online, as example:

- [How to export DataTable to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207869/how-to-export-datatable-to-excel)
- [Export data from dataset to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790431/export-data-from-dataset-to-excel)
- [Exporting DataTable to Excel in C# Using Interop](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/exporting-datatable-to-excel-in-C-Sharp-using-interop/)
- [Export DataTable to Excel sheet in C# and VB.NET](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/examples/c-sharp-export-datatable-to-excel/501)
- [Export DataSet into Excel using C# Excel Interop](https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/753207/Export-DataSet-into-Excel-using-Csharp-Excel-Inter)