# How to create an excel file and deliver to the screen using C# in a MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel

Please send code samples if you can, Thanks!

Comment: @AndyC: You need to elaborate.  What do you mean "to the screen".  Also, what is the minimum format of Excel that must be supported?

Answer (score 2):

The Excel 2007 format can be created without Excel, as it's just a zip file containing XML files, I've generated Word 2007 docs before on the fly and served them from a web page without Word installed.

There's an article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/ExcelPackage.aspx) on CodeProject

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to 3d-party form control.

I found next topics about this issue:

- [Is there a control which emulates Excel functionality but is not Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413538/is-there-a-control-which-emulates-excel-functionality-but-is-not-excel)
- [ASP.Net web server control that generates HTML and Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236185/asp-net-web-server-control-that-generates-html-and-excel)

and much more with tags `excel`, `control`, `asp.net`, etc

I think the best implementation would be non-free [Google: excel+reports+asp.net](http://www.google.ru/search?q=asp.net+excel+reports) has a number of solutions

Answer (score 0):

If you're not militant about it being "an excel file" and actually mean "A file with some data I have, loaded with excel", then all you have to do is create a .csv and open it programatically with excel.  It'll look the same as a 'real' excel file, mostly-kinda.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this: http://code.google.com/p/excel-generator/

Hope it helps!